# Spartacus storefront | Wrong NGRX state update | SetDeliveryMode action in checkout custom feature state in addition to updating its own PROCESS state

Tags: ngrx-store, spartacus-storefront

I have been creating a new feature that delivery mode contain custom delivery slots.I have added new actions(StateUtils.EntityLoadAction), effects, reducers etc for new custom delivery slot which is working fine and creating a feature state (LoaderState) "SelectedDeliverySlot".

Custom slot feature is working fine and its state is also being captured.

But when i am switching deliveryMode then "SetDeliveryMode" action is updating its PROCESS state and also removing newly independent Feature state.

I am not able to understand why my Custom feature state is being removed on selection of delivery mode.

Some code excepts

Newly Created SetDeliverySlot action

```
export class SetDeliverySlot extends StateUtils.EntityLoadAction {
readonly type = "[DeliverySlot] set delivery slot";
constructor(
  // public payload: { userId: string; cartId: string; selectedDate :string; selectedModeId:string, selectedSlotId: string }
  public payload: { userId: string; cartId: string; selectedDate :string; modeId:string, selectedSlotId: string }
) {
  super("process", "setDeliverySlot");
}
```

}

Custom feature state

[App State](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6bTe.png)

Switching to another mode "SetDeliveryMode" action called and its diff (update in application state and somehow removing deliverySlot state also)

[Diff for SetDeliveryMode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juGqZ.png)

I am not able to understand that each action is responsible for updating its own state so why deliveryMode action is removing another state and where in code this removal is being happened.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can double check is the `type` field of your custom actions.  If one of your custom actions has the same string value in the `type` field than one of the delivery mode related actions, this could cause the delivery mode action to be handled by your custom feature reducer as well, producing the kind of behaviour you observe.

On the develop branch, you can see the delivery mode actions in [this source file](https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/blob/develop/projects/core/src/checkout/store/actions/checkout.action.ts).  You can switch to the release branch that matches your Spartacus version for the most accurate comparison.

Comment: Yes, verified. It is different. OOTB delivermode has type SET_DELIVERY_MODE = '[Checkout] Set Delivery Mode';; And my Custom Slot has type = "[DeliverySlot] set delivery slot" And my reducer is using my own slot action type 

@Effect()
setDeliverySlot$: Observable<
    | SetDeliverySlotFail
    | SetDeliverySlotSuccess
> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType('[DeliverySlot] Set Delivery Slot'),
    map((action: any) => action.payload),
    mergeMap((payload) => { //custom code } );